# Gitlab CI Pages not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using GitlabCI with my own Gitlab Runner based on docker and properly registered

This is how I run the runner using docker and docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services: 
  gitlab_runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v11.3.1
    restart: always
    container_name: gitlab_runner_my_project
    environment:
      - CI_SERVER_URL=https://gitlab.com/
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/runner:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
```

And this is my runner configuration

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner for my project"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "my-token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable-dind"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = true
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    run_untagged = true
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "cache"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      AccessKey = "AWSkey"
      SecretKey = "AWSsecret"
      BucketName = "grcache"
      Insecure = false
```

with the following code, I can run test, coverage, deploy and supposedly publish Page with the coverage report.

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  image: ruby:2.5.1
  tags:
    - my_tag
  stage: test
  services:
    - mongo:3.6.3
  variables:
    RAILS_ENV: test
    MONGODB_URI: ...
  before_script:
    - bundle install
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec spec/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/*

staging_deploy:
    .
    .
    .

pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  tags:
    - my_tag
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - cp -r coverage/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 30 days
  only:
    - test-coverage
```

The test run nicely with coverage, also the deploy and supposedly publishing page. The next picture shows the logs of Pages job.

Those are the jobs shown in the pipeline.

[image]

[image]

Everything looks to be fine when I visit Pages section on my project.

[image]

But when I want to visit the page. BOOOMMMMM

[image]

Comment: Does Gitlab create another job named `pages:deploy` for you?

Comment: Yes, Gasol. I edit the question for showing the jobs in the pipeline.

Comment: Does your *coverage* folder include a file called *index.html*?

Comment: Yes Philipp Ludwig, it includes. It is inside the coverage folder. I also tryed copying the content of the that folder in public instead of copying the folder it self and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add an asterisk at the end of `coverage` path? I guess that maybe some of the files or the whole dir `coverage` is untracked by git. In that case, changing the stored artifacts path from the test stage could help:

```
artifacts:
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - coverage/
```

Just for the fast dirty debugging, you can always add some scripts to the .gitlab-ci.yml to see what is in the relevant dirs before and after copying operation:

```
script:
  - ls -al
  - ls -al coverage
  - ls -al public
  - cp -r coverage/ public/
  - ls -al coverage
  - ls -al public
```

Probably this will yield some light on the problem. Your .gitlab-ci.yml looks fine.

EDIT: as you said, maybe this is a permission problem. I doubt that this could help, since this `public` dir is an artifact and permissions should not matter on that. But just to check you could modify permissions on it:

```
script:
  - chmod -R 755 public
```

Comment: I tried your advice for easy debugging, and also ls public/coverage and everything looks fine. All files are already copied. Something maybe interesting is that all permissions are in the way root:root becuase I use a docker based runner. So far the result is the same.

Comment: I'd go for a different runner then to check it (these notorious permissions, I also use docker executors and it's a bit confusing, since there is a gitlab-runner user on CI), if this is an option for you, try only the smallest page deploy bit from the .gitlab-ci.yml on a shared runner provided by gitlab. I've updated my answer with permissions suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can check actual pages URL by checking environment variable:

```
pages:
  ...
  script:
    - ... others scripts
    - echo $CI_PAGES_URL
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```